# Java JIT-compiler: is dead code removed forever?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I have follow test class for checking JIT-compiler logic:

```
public static final int COUNT = 2_000_000_000;

public static final MyLogger LOG = new MyLogger(false);

//Here IS_DEBUG is false
public static final boolean IS_DEBUG = LOG.isDebug();

private void run() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println(getSum(COUNT));

    //Compilation without OSR
    System.out.println(getSum(COUNT + 2));

    //Change value IS_DEBUG -> true over reflection
    setFinalStatic(TestDeadCode.class.getField("IS_DEBUG"), true);
    //Show true
    System.out.println(IS_DEBUG);
    
    COUNT = COUNT / 2;
    System.out.println(getSum(COUNT + 3));
}

private int getSum(int count)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        result = result + 1;
        if (IS_DEBUG)
        {
            //Dead code here
            System.out.println("debug: " + result);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If i call method `run()` then "dead code"

`System.out.println("debug: " + result);`

is executed never. Is it JVM bug?

Java version:

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

UPDATE: PrintCompilation output:

> ```
> 79    1 %           com.nau.sample.deadcode.TestDeadCode::getSum @ 7 (34 bytes)
>
> 85    1             com.nau.sample.deadcode.TestDeadCode::getSum (34 bytes)
> ```

Comment: Actually most likely (if `LOG.isDebug()` is known at compile time) there is javac acts, not JIT compiler.

Comment: javac cannot predict "LOG.isDebug()" value.

Comment: as you can see  System.out.println(IS_DEBUG) shows "true" after setFinalStatic()

Comment: when i change COUNT to 100 "dead code" is executed

Comment: and what `"-XX:+PrintCompilation"` says?

Comment: added to post PrintCompilation output

Comment: The value of a (primitive) `static final` variable is *replaced* at compile time everywhere it is referenced. So the code using the variable does no longer reference it, it just "uses" the value available at compile time. Not sure if this is also true in your case (because your static final is initialized by a method call), but it sure sounds as if exactly that would happen.

Comment: Looks like this is bad idea to change value of final attributes :)

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bug; I'd call this exactly what you should expect if you go messing around with reflection.

Comment: I checked that assembly code doesn't contain "if (debug)" instruction. Therefore, It is dead code elimination really